# Combination of non-unique foreign keys to create primary key?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table in SQLAlchemy which would connect a movie and a category and give it a score (The Shining in the category Thriller might have a score of 700 whilst The Shining in the category Drama might have a score of 540 etc).

This means that the table will include many references to The Shining and many references to Thriller but only one case where it is the combination of The Shining and Thriller which would also include the score of 700. This picture explains it well.[image]

Category and Movie are classes of their own.

So searching for an answer I found that I could have multiple primary keys but that wouldn't work in this case since primary keys have to be unique and the Movie ID and Category ID aren't unique.

I found the word "Composite Key" which sounds like what I'm looking for but demonstrated in SQLAlchemy it doesn't seem to do the same thing as I thought it would.

How would I go about making a table that does what I'm looking for? AKA the "Category Movie Scores" from the picture?
And the reason I'm not just creating a regular ID that would serve as a primary key is that it would never ever be used, I'm only everu querying this table with the Movie and Category ID's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved with an [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html?highlight=relationship#association-object). Which is a Many-To-Many relationship based on an object to be able to store additional data.

```py
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    movie_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'), primary_key=True)
    score = Column(Integer)
    votes = Column(Integer)
    category = relationship("Category", back_populates="movies")
    movie = relationship("Movie", back_populates="categories")

class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movie'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    categories = relationship("Association", back_populates="movie")

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    movies = relationship("Association", back_populates="category")
```

*Use `sqlite_autoincrement=True` with [sqlite](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#using-the-autoincrement-keyword) to create the autoincrement on database level.*

Before you can append a category to the movie it needs to be associated with an association instance:

```py
# create movie, append a category via association
m = Movie()
a = Association(score=700, votes=0)
a.category = Category()
m.categories.append(a)

# iterate through category objects via association, including association
# attributes
for assoc in m.categories:
    print(assoc.score)
    print(assoc.category)
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a ton!
Will have to dig deeper into association objects to get a grasp of what is going on.

Comment: All right this seemed to work but now I am being told: `Column 'association.category_id' is marked as a member of the primary key for table 'association', but has no Python-side or server-side default generator indicated, nor does it indicate 'autoincrement=True' or 'nullable=True', and no explicit value is passed.  Primary key columns typically may not store NULL. Note that as of SQLAlchemy 1.1, 'autoincrement=True' must be indicated explicitly for composite (e.g. multicolumn) primary keys if AUTO_INCREMENT/SERIAL/IDENTITY behavior is expected for one of the columns in the primary key.`

Comment: Okay the fix was to add `a.movie = m` since it didn't seem to get the movie automatically when the association was appended to it. Not sure why :(

Comment: @cobble, I've changed the answer to get rid of the warning. Very strange you need to set `a.movie = m` as this should be handled by `append` in the model. I've tested it locally and the results are as expected without setting it.

Comment: Ah ok then I might know why it happens.

I'm importing all the data from another database meaning that I'm setting the ID directly (therefore the autoincrement doesn't do anything). And I too thought it was weird that I needed to set it since my understanding of the tables were the same as yours, I'll keep playing around with it and seeing if I get any different results. Thank you still!